# Automatically rerun datafactory controller pipiline on failure

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

In our setup we have numerous pipelines, wrapped in controller pipelines. These are again in a "master" pipline. On occations, some activity pipeline fail for a number of reasons, this could be timeout, being unable to get at secret from the KeyVault etc. I know that we can put a retry on a copydata task, but we have like 500+. My question is - is there a way in which I can automatically re-run a controller pipeline from failed activity ?
BR Tom

Comment: I think the retry option is your best bet. However modifying 500+ copy tasks is a lot of work. Using source control, you can modify the policy settings easily by using a find and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such feature available in the Azure Data Factory. You can raise a feature request here.

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/post/

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.